# Question: It's possible to use Angular version without authorization?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I want to use Abp as base for my company projects, actually we use Oracle for Database.

The problem is all bussiness logic including Users, Roles are managed by the database, in my case I don't need to use authorization.

Really I need a clean version of the framework wihout any table. I know I can download the framework like this If I don't mark the check "Include login, register, user, role and tenant management pages." but this template is for MVC and I need something like this but for Angular.

My question is

Is there any way I can get the framework like this for angular?

Any way to clean It and how can I do it?

I hope you can help me, I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you unslect **Include login, register, user, role and tenant management pages**, it does not include most of them and gives you a clean project. Did you check that?

[image]

Comment: Yes, I've check it even I've say it in my question, the problem is in this way when the project it's downloaded is a MVC version I need Angular version.